# What's creating the horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I need your help people.

I've searched throughout the seven seas of my webpage.

I tried to apply `overflow: hidden` in almost every tag.

I know it's because of the animation I'm using on the slider. I want to add an `overflow: hidden` to it but it doesn't seem to work.

I even commented everything else to see things through. Here's the page [link](http://inovlancer.com/projetos/ferbancozi.pt/)

I need a life savior.

EDIT: the scrollbar is slightly seen on page load.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 The link only has what I'm looking for. As I said, I commented everything else.

Comment: That's great, please post a code example *in your question*.

Comment: @j08691 I'm really sorry but I don't believe I should post the full nivo-slider  css code here as I don't even know what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's correct, you shouldn't. You should  however, post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Check your widths, overflow only affects content that exceeds the container width and height. Also your preloader and body tags are set to show overflow.

Comment: @Brino I know, it's the slider incoming animation that exceeds the window width BUT what I want is to find where's the problem and add an overflow: hidden to it

Comment: Original code in case it gets changed: http://pastebin.com/2cn4vYku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}`

This could be `overflow-y` but im pretty sure its `x`

It does appear to be some plugin creating this extra space on the load in effect. Try that CSS and see if it helps anything. It may just be that jQuery however.

Comment: Setting priority in your CSS with `!important` will help if you fail to remove the 'visible' tag in your html

Comment: I added just the html overflow-x hidden and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your body tag has inline css for `overflow:visible'. Remove this and your css file should take precedence. Otherwise set your css file to use

```
body { overflow: hidden !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    })
    //]]>
</script>
```

This script at the end of your HTML file is adding `overflow:visible` to your `<body>` tag on load. Try removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example with chrome dev tools shows that your body tag is set to "overflow:visible". Removing that should solve the problem.

Comment: That's weird, I have this on my css.css file: body{overflow: hidden;} Can it be that some script is creating it?